# constantly monitoring directory/files(s) for error reporting

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I need to watch a directory for changes in files(s) (existing or newly created) and count the number of times `ERROR` appears in the log. The moment it sees a new line with `OKAY` in it, it resets the error-counter to 0 (zero). The script keeps repeating the same procedure once it finds the `ERROR` in the new lines again.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
log="/tmp/running.txt"
ref=${log}.ref
TERR=${TERR:-0}

if [ -e $log ]; then
    if [ ! -e $ref ] || find $log -newer $ref | grep . > /dev/null
    then
        touch -r $log $ref
        gStr="tail -1 $log | grep -m1 -Fe 'ERROR'"
        echo -e "[$(date)] #-------------- CHANGE(s) DETECTED --------------#"

        [[ -n $(eval $gStr) ]] \
        && { echo " ---- $(eval $gStr) --- "; export TERR=$(( TERR+1 )); } \
        || { echo -e " ***** It's OKAY now *****"; export TERR=0; }
        echo "Error counter: $TERR"

        echo -e "[$(date)] #-------------- End of Check ---------------#\n"
    fi
fi
```

I started with a single file (to check, as opposed to multiple files in the directory) and this is what I came up so far, which is working okay in terms of catching `ERROR` and `OKAY` in the new lines, but can't figure out to keep track of the number of error reporting, before it sees `OKAY`. I tried running this scrit `(. ./chkError.sh)` without any joy. The `TERR=$((TERR+1))` doesn't seem to be working. Any idea how do I do that?

Another associated issue is, I'm running this script as a cron-job, i.e. running in every minute, which may not sufficient. What else I can do keep it running in the background? cheers!!

Comment: Check out inotify and inotifytools.

Comment: @wildplasser: already checked out that possibility but the problem is `inotify|inotifytools` is not part of the standard installation and I cannot make sure those tools are installed on that particular node. So got to be with things that are available. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The linux kernel includes a relatively inexpensive subsystem for doing exactly this thing and is the most reliable and proven way to do what you want. You register a "watch" in your code to look for specific events on the directory and the kernel notifies you when one happens and your code then runs a function and you can then do something with the file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

I realise that you probably don't want to write C code, but it is relatively easy to write something in Python or Perl to do this if you know those languages? Or even just a wrapper to register the inotify watch and then trigger a shell script.

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify.

Comment: I can use Python (or perl, if I really need to) but as long as it uses the tools, available in the standard library: In that case, which is not true for `pyinotify`. Looking at the `inotify` but again it requires `inotify-tools` to be per-installed - right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: inotify is a core linux kernel subsystem and always available. The libraries (pyinotify) or command line tools (inotify-tools) that use that core kernel inotify subsystem, may or may not be in your distro. If not, and you don't want to install them, then you'd have to write C program compiled against libraries directly to use inotify.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine time stamp guard with incremental processing ([my 20-liner](http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/incremental-text-file-monitoring)), pipe the output through a configurable filter, in your case `| egrep '^ERROR'` and thus report just new errors.

If you really need to have it close to real time then run `tail -f xxx.log` monitors on each file with conflating alerts batching as an output filter.